# AngularJS and selenium

Tags: angularjs, selenium

I have a following text box in angularjs site:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here" class="ng-  pristine ng-valid">
```

I want to find it using selenium webdriver for chrome as follows:

```
public class LoginTest {
   private WebDriver driver;
   private String baseUrl;

   @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "C:/Users/sneh.tripathi/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
   baseUrl = "http://angularjs.org/";
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

   @Test
   public void testLogin() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl);
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.ng-valid.ng-dirty")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.ng-valid.ng-dirty")).sendKeys("sneh");
```

But i am not able to run the above JUnit test and geting NoSuchElementFound element

Comment: Your input has the class ng-pristine. You're selecting elements with the class ng-dirty.

Comment: so shall i use: driver.findElement(By.className("ng-pristine")).clear();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using those classes to target interacting with elements they are added by the framework and its better to target the actual element instead.  Unless of course you are looking for "special cases" where data is untouched/dirty/invalid.

Either add a name or target via

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[ng-model="yourName"]")).clear();
```