# Selecting elements by ng-model attribute with selenium-webdriver

Tags: ruby, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Ruby and the gem selenium-webdriver
I am working with an angular form that I have no control over and would like to know how to find elements via their ng-model attributes.

Here is an example select element:

```
<select class="medium-3 small-12 columns ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-model="ctrl.type" ng-options="type.name for type in ctrl.admissions">
```

I have located some code in JavaScript, but I'm unsure how to translate it over for Ruby:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[ng-model="yourName"]"))
```

Here's a link to that thread: [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029623/angularjs-and-selenium)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find_element()` with `:css`:

```
driver.find_element(:css, 'input[ng-model="MyModel"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xPath which is a more easier way to detect Angular-JS Elements

Comment: I would not say it is easier - it is just a different location technique.

Comment: I'd say stay away from xpath. Small changes in UI and you'll have to rewrite chunks of your test again as the xpath would have changed.